# Logcat doesn't show phone process

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-logcat

I buyed new phone and try to use it for debugging. But my IntelliJ Idea doesn't see any processes on phone. Filters also don't work.

Screen with old phone:

[image]

Screen with new phone:

[image]

*** === UPDATE === ***

[image]

Comment: Not sure about this, any chance you check whether debugging mode is enabled on the phone ?

Comment: It is, otherwise the device would not be visible at all.

Comment: I apdated post with debug Settings screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to explicitly set the [debug flag](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug) in your manifest:

```
<application android:debuggable="true"> ... </application>
```

I understand that the code did not change, and therefore you expect identical behavior, but different Android versions behave differently :)

Comment: Oh.. that's my bad. I always change this setting for production and forgot to set it back.

Comment: Also be sure while deploying your application make android:debuggable="false" or remove it..its good practice..